# reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk_url_kwarg' - UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying use Django built-in class `UpdateView` to update an image model

The model is:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
 return '/'.join(['studyoffer_images', instance.study_offer.slug, filename])


class UploadStudyOffer(models.Model):

    study_offer = models.ForeignKey(StudiesOffert, related_name='uploadsstudyoffer')

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, verbose_name='Seleccionar imagen')
    # images folder per object

    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Destacada',
                                   help_text='Indica si la imagen aparecera en el carrusel')
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Activa',
                                 help_text='Indica si una imagen de oferta esta habilitada o disponible')

    objects = UploadStudyOfferManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.study_offer.ad_title
```

The form of this model is:

```
class StudyOfferImagesUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadStudyOffer
        fields = ('image', 'active', 'featured')
```

What I want now is to allow the user to edit an image and can change it and change the status image (`featured`, `active`, `thumbnail`)

Then I build my `StudyOfferImageUpdateView` to update the image attributes:

```
class StudyOfferImageUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UserProfileDataMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UploadStudyOffer
    form_class = StudyOfferImagesUploadForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("host:edit-study-offer-image", pk_url_kwarg='pk')
    success_message = "Imagen actualizada"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StudyOfferImageUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        user = self.request.user
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(UploadStudyOffer, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

The URL to access this view is:

```
url(r"^study-offer/edit/images/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",
        StudyOfferImageUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='edit-study-offer-image'
    ),
```

When I want edit my image the template is this:

```
{% block body_content %}

<h2>Editar imágen</h2>
<form role="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="submit-button"> 
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This template is renderized correctly, but when I press the `Update` submit button, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /host/study-offer/edit/images/47/
Exception Value: reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk_url_kwarg'
```

This error exist, because in my `StudyOfferImageUpdateView` Django does not accept the `success_url = reverse_lazy("host:edit-study-offer-image", pk_url_kwarg='pk')`

I try print the `pk_url_kwarg='pk'` sentence inside my `StudyOfferImageUpdateView`

```
q=pk_url_kwarg='pk'
    print(q)
```

And the output when I enter to my `StudyOfferImageUpdateView` via browser is:

```
# pk string, is not the pk value
pk
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 24, 2017 - 15:58:55
Django version 1.10.7, using settings 'hostayni.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[24/Oct/2017 15:58:57] "GET /host/study-offer/edit/images/47/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8559
```

I know that in the `get_context_data()` method the `pk_url_kwarg='pk'` sentence it's works, I am passing it in the `success_url = reverse_lazy("host:edit-study-offer-image", pk_url_kwarg='pk')` and arrive a string `pk` and for tis reason my workflow is breaked.

How to can I pass the correct parameter in my `success_url = reverse_lazy("host:edit-study-offer-image", pk_url_kwarg='pk')` which expect a `pk` image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, when you call `reverse` or `reverse_lazy`, you provide the arguments and keyword arguments in `args` and `kwargs`. You can't do `pk_url_kwarg='pk'`, you need to do `kwargs={'pk_url_kwarg': 'pk'}`.

However you don't want to use the strings `'pk_url_kwarg'` and `'pk'` in the `kwargs` dictionary, you want to use the variables `self.pk_url_kwarg` and `self.kwargs['pk']` from the view.

You can't access these variables if you set `success_url`, so you need to override `get_success_url` instead.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("host:edit-study-offer-image", kwargs={self.pk_url_kwarg:self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Since your view isn't intended to be subclassed and customised, I don't think you need to use `pk_url_kwarg` at all. I would simplify the code by hardcoding `'pk'`.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("host:edit-study-offer-image", kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Or use `args` instead:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("host:edit-study-offer-image", args=[self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Correct, I was confused about of the keyword to use. In the [Classy Class-Based Views-UpdateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) I was watching the `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'` attribute but I am not referencing of a correct way. Tahnks a lot for you. Best Regards :D

Comment: The `pk_url_kwarg` option gives you more flexibility when using class based views, but the extra level of indirection makes it more complicated. In this case I would probably simplify it to `kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}`.

Comment: @mohammedqudah that's nice of you to say. I've been using Django for several years, so it's nice to be able to help out other users. Having said that, there are many other Django developers with much deeper knowledge of Django than me.

Comment: sorry for using the comments like this,  but i am 15 years old and i don't what to do next i used django for one year and i want someone to tell me what to do next can you help me : ), my email: *mohammedalqudah@hotmail.com*

Comment: @mohammedqudah I'm afraid I can't give you a list of things to work on. I think you'll learn the most if you choose a small project to build and then work on it. When you hit challenges you'll be more motivated to solve them because you're excited about the project.

Comment: oh my god, this is my way of learning any language, that's how i learned django and python